# Can disable or comment inside value of href in anchor tag?

Tags: html

My problem is i wanna have some comment or disable some text inside value of href attribute of anchor tag.
I mean look like this:

```
<a href="http://[domain.com]stackoverflow.com">Jquery.com</a>
```

And when i click url redirect to stackoverflow.com and behave with domain.com like a comment or don't have any effect to link. Value in square bracket just like a comment inside url :**[domain.com]**

Can i do this without using jquery or javascript just like // or /**/ for normal comment inside code.

Please help me and thanks for reading.

Comment: Are u using html with another technology? Like php or something? And why you want to comment it? What's your need? Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Comments in HTML are this way :
`<!-- [domain.com] -->`
but that won't work in your case.

Why do you need to leave the [domain.com] if you want it to be effectless ?

Anyway, you could do something like that :

```
<a href="http://[domain.com]stackoverflow.com" class="linkWithComment">Jquery.com</a>
```

and JS:

```
$('a.linkWithComment').click(function(e) {
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').replace(/\[(.*)\]/g,''));        
});
```

Here's a JSFiddle for it : http://jsfiddle.net/kJDUB/

BUT be aware that this is absolutely not a recommended behaviour: SEO is probably broken, and there a many solutions to achieve same behaviour while being cleaner (like HTML5 tags : `<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" data-other-domain="domain.com">Jquery.com</a>`
and you can still reach the domain.com ...)

Comment: Thanks TechAddict and Augustin Reidinger for help me soon! Why i do it ? My purpose just for SEO with anchor tag is rel="dofollow". When i create a article or promote my items on forum or some website. All anchor tag with rel="nofollow" and guess what. I try to figure out how it is. And i found that if my url have forum's domain name or website's domain name itself before my domain name then my anchor tag will be "dofollow". That reason why i want to add their domain name before my domain name. This is hack i think so i am afraid to talk real reason! Sorry about that guys. Please help. Thanks.